# How do I build a Water Conveyor?

Tags: farlanders

In *Farlanders*, I found water underground and would like to pump it to my colony just above it.

[image: screenshot]

I already researched "Water Conveyor", but I don't know where this building option can be found to be built.

Where is it located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the top of an Elevator.

[image]